# How to prove "square arrangement product" converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is well known that when we multiply two infinite series, say $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ and  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i$, then their "product"  $(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i )\cdot(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i)$ may depend on how $a_i b_j$s are arranged even when both  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ and  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i$ converge. One famous example is the **[Cauchy product](http://demo.activemath.org/ActiveMath2/main/view.cmd;jsessionid=073129ED649CD6AFA74AFD47B281D0B6?book=LeAM_calculusCompleteRec&page=66)** in which they are arranged diagonally. Cauchy product converges if both $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i$ converge absolutely but may diverge if they converge only conditionally.
Another famous arrangement is the "square arrangement" (I'm sorry I don't know how to describe it terminologically. You can take at look at **the picture below.**). In my textbook it claims that in the "square arrangement" the requirement for the convergence of the product is a bit weaker: both $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ converge, whether conditionally or absolutely. Unluckily the textbook doesn't give a proof on this, and I have tried googling it but got nothing (it might be because I don't know the accurate terminology). Can you help me about it? Any hint or just telling me the right terminology will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

A diagram of "square arrangement" here:
[image]
The "square arrangement product" is thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d_i$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the partial sums:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^Nd_i=\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^Na_i\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Exactly! That's all it takes for a perfect proof. Thank you so much!

Comment: And may I ask how to describe such a product terminologically (or at least properly) in English? "square arrangement product" sounds quite awkward to me.

Comment: English is not my native language. I find _square product_ quite descriptive.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway.